# What is the difference in Swift between 'unowned(safe)' and 'unowned(unsafe)'?

Tags: memory-management, swift, automatic-ref-counting

Apple's [*Swift Programming Language Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html) mentions the *capture specifiers* `unowned(safe)` and `unowned(unsafe)`, in addition to `weak` and `unowned`.

I (think I) understand the differences between `weak` and `unowned`; but what is the difference between `unowned(safe)` and `unowned(unsafe)`? The guide doesn't say.

---

Please: Don't rely on simply stating an Objective-C equivalent.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

From what I understand, although I can't find a definitive source from Apple, `unowned` can be broken into two flavors, `safe` and `unsafe`.

A bare `unowned` is `unowned(safe)`: it is a specially wrapped reference which will throw an exception when a dealloced instance is referenced.

The special case is `unowned(unsafe)`: it is the Swift equivalent of Objective C's `@property (assign)` or `__unsafe_unretained`. It should not be used in a Swift program, because its purpose is to bridge to code written in Objective C.

So, you will see `unowned(unsafe)` when looking at the import wrapper for Cocoa classes, but don't use it unless you have to, and you will know when you have to.

---

**Update**

`__unsafe_unretained` is a simple pointer. It will not know when the instance being pointed at has be dealloced, so when it's dereferenced, the underlying memory could be garbage.

If you have a defect where a dealloced `__unsafe_unretained` variable is being used, you will see erratic behavior. Sometimes enough of that memory location is good enough so the code will run, sometimes it will have been partially overwritten so you will get very odd crashes, and sometimes that memory location will contain a new object so you will get unrecognized selector exceptions.

[Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW4)

> `__unsafe_unretained` specifies a reference that does not keep the referenced object alive and is not set to nil when there are no strong references to the object. If the object it references is deallocated, the pointer is left dangling.

Comment: But what do those Objective-C equivalents mean?

Comment: So, to summarize, unlike `strong` references, `weak` and all the `unowned`s do not contribute to reference counting. So once all `strong` references are gone, the instance referenced will be deallocated (when only `weak` and `unowned` references to it remain); `weak` references will be set to `nil` (they thus have optional type), while `unowned` will not be. However `unowned(safe)` references to deallocated instances will throw a predictable exception when accessed, while `unowned(unsafe)` references will act like a simple old pointer and behave unpredictably. Right?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius, no that’s not right. `unowned` and `unowned(safe)` do incur reference counting cost—that is the cost of safety, and why even make `unowned(unsafe)` available otherwise?—and it’s currently worse than regular strong reference counting cost because ARC isn’t optimizing for it.  Neither throws an exception; they trap when misused, permanently stopping the program.

Answer (score 28):

Here is a quote from [Apple Developer Forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/987086):

## `unowned` vs `unowned(safe)` vs `unowned(unsafe)`

> `unowned(safe)` is a non-owning reference that asserts on access that
>   the object is still alive. It's sort of like a weak optional reference
>   that's implicitly unwrapped with `x!` every time it's accessed.
>   `unowned(unsafe)` is like `__unsafe_unretained` in ARC—it's a non-owning
>   reference, but there's no runtime check that the object is still alive
>   on access, so dangling references will reach into garbage memory.
>   `unowned` is always a synonym for `unowned(safe)` currently, but the
>   intent is that it will be optimized to `unowned(unsafe)` in `-Ofast`
>   builds when runtime checks are disabled.

Comment: I just debugged a crash using unowned with runtime checks disabled, compiled optimized, where __deallocating_deinit asserted in the presence of an unowned reference to a deleted object. (Though my code never referenced it after the object went away.)

So there is still a difference between unowned(unsafe) and unowned compiled with safety checks disabled.

Detailed thread on this:
https://twitter.com/RonAvitzur/status/1463576340519473159

Answer (score 13):

Variable is accessed when it was dellocated already with attribute:

## unowned

- Program knows it is invalid, and goes crash immediately.
- Behavior is defined.

## unowned(unsafe)

- Program knows nothing.
- It may crash immediately.
- It may access unknown memory address and have strange state until it dies at surprise location.
- Behavior is **undefined**. Life gets harder.

Answer (score 5):

A simple Definition. which would clear the confusion.

-- unowned attributes : If you try to access an unowned reference after the instance that it refers to is deallocated, your program will crash.

-- unowned(Unsafe) attributes: If you try to access an unsafe unowned reference after the instance that it refers to is deallocated, your program will try to access the memory location where the instance used to be, which is an unsafe operation. (no guarantee wether this would executes or crashes)

Answer (score 0):

In simple words

`unowned(safe)` or simply `unowned` - Crash the application if we try to refer the deallocated object.

`unowned(unsafe)` - Don't crash the application but instead try to find the memory location where the referred object was stored before de-initialisation.

Consider example -

```
class Customer {
    let name: String
    var card: CreditCard?
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
    deinit {
        print("\(name) is being deinitialized")
        print("It's Credit card is - ", card)
    }
}


class CreditCard {
    let number: UInt64
    unowned(unsafe) let customer: Customer
    init(number: UInt64, customer: Customer) {
        self.number = number
        self.customer = customer
    }
    deinit {
        print("Card #\(number) is being deinitialized")
        print("It's customer is - ", customer.name)
    }
}

var customer: Customer? = Customer(name: "Stackoverflow")
customer!.card = CreditCard(number: 1234_5678_9012_3456, customer: customer!)
customer = nil
```

When you run this code in playground then your will get the following output -

```
Stackoverflow is being deinitialized
It's Credit card -  Optional(__lldb_expr_16.CreditCard)
Card #1234567890123456 is being deinitialized
It's customer -  Stackoverflow
```

**The main thing to check here is even the Stackoverflow was deinitialised but still we can print that in CreditCard's deinit call**

**If you will try to call the same code with `unowned` instead of `unowned(unsafe)` then it will crash with following logs**

```
Stackoverflow is being deinitialized
It's Credit card -  Optional(__lldb_expr_20.CreditCard)
Card #1234567890123456 is being deinitialized
Fatal error: Attempted to read an unowned reference but object 0x600000291830 was already deallocated
```