# Type and declaration restrictions on Swift capture specifiers

Tags: swift, automatic-ref-counting, option-type

I'm confused about the type requirements and declaration restrictions for Swift *capture specifiers*. The documentation says that `weak` references must be `var` and "of optional type", and that `unowned` references must be of non-optional type. But Apple's own API reference [has examples](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/transitioningDelegate) of `unowned(unsafe)` references declared as optionals, while the Xcode interface builder creates `weak` outlets and actions that are implicitly unwrapped (which is not always clearly "of optional type" in the language reference).

What types are required for each of the Swift capture specifiers? Which must be `var` and which can be `let`?

---

FWIW, I think its

- `weak` can be `Type?` or `Type!`, but not `Type`; and must be `var`
- `unowned(safe)` ([same as `unowned`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26553924/656912)) must be `Type`; and may be `let`
- `unowned(unsafe)` can be `Type?` or `Type!`; and may be `let`

but I'm far from sure.

Answer (score 0):

First the Cocoa`or Cocoa touch APIs are imported in swift from`objective-c`. They are mapped in swift with best possible ways.So that both can interoperable.

Those `unowned(unsafe)` properties are marked as `assign` in ObjC. These are `unsafe` and ARC doesn't retain the object, and it doesn't make sure the reference gets reset to `nil if the object is deallocated. These are old apple API and not changed with ARC and remain as`assign`but you should make`delegateweak`
Do not look for headers for best practices in swift they have made many tricks to make swift and objective-c interoperable and if you do what headers do than you loose all safety swift proveide.

You are right

**weak** should be `optional` as contain `nil` automatically if objects get deallocate and no other pointer retain it

**unowned(safe)** should not be `optional` and will not reset to `nil`if objects deal-located

**unowned(unsafe)** can or can not be `optional` as it not provide any safety by ARC for object deal-location and do not reset to `nil`.You should not use this in swift program.Use `unowned` if needed.It is just for interoperability.

**weak** is always `var` because it can be changed when objects deallocate and set to `nil`.

**unowned(safe)** and **unowned(unsafe)**  can be both `var` or `let` as they are dependent on you and run-time will not change these variables.

Note:You can not declare a **unowned(unsafe)** as `optional` in swift program.Its for just interoperability and should not be used in swift.They have made this because of `assign` or `unretain` properties can be `nil`

Comment: It isn't clear how this maps to the question (or my guess at an answer). Can you focus/clarify?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius please let me know which parts need clarification.

Comment: Thanks, that's much better. If you could condense a bit (e.g. follow the structure of my FWIW, which say about the same thing though much more clearly).