# Swift Weak Reference Much Slower than Strong Reference

Tags: swift, performance, weak-references, strong-references, unowned-references

I'm building a physics engine in Swift. After making some recent additions to the engine and running the benchmarking tests I noticed the performance was drastically slower. For example, in the screenshots below you can see how the FPS dropped from 60 to 3 FPS (FPS is in the bottom-right corner). Eventually, I traced the problem down to just a single line of code:

```
final class Shape {
    ...
    weak var body: Body! // This guy
    ...
}
```

[image]
[image]

At some point in my additions I added a weak reference from the `Shape` class to the `Body` class. This is to prevent a strong reference cycle, as `Body` also has a strong reference to `Shape`.

Unfortunately, it appears weak references have a significant overhead (I suppose the extra steps in nulling it out). I decided to investigate this further by building a massively simplified version of the physics engine below and benchmarking different reference types.

---

```
import Foundation

final class Body {
    let shape: Shape
    var position = CGPoint()
    init(shape: Shape) {
        self.shape = shape
        shape.body = self
        
    }
}

final class Shape {
    weak var body: Body! //****** This line is the problem ******
    var vertices: [CGPoint] = []
    init() {
        for _ in 0 ..< 8 {
            self.vertices.append( CGPoint(x:CGFloat.random(in: -10...10), y:CGFloat.random(in: -10...10) ))
        }
    }
}

var bodies: [Body] = []
for _ in 0 ..< 1000 {
    bodies.append(Body(shape: Shape()))
}

var pairs: [(Shape,Shape)] = []
for i in 0 ..< bodies.count {
    let a = bodies[i]
    for j in i + 1 ..< bodies.count {
        let b = bodies[j]
        pairs.append((a.shape,b.shape))
    }
}

/*
 Benchmarking some random computation performed on the pairs.
 Normally this would be collision detection, impulse resolution, etc.
 */
let startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
for (a,b) in pairs {
    var t: CGFloat = 0
    for v in a.vertices {
        t += v.x*v.x + v.y*v.y
    }
    for v in b.vertices {
        t += v.x*v.x + v.y*v.y
    }
    a.body.position.x += t
    a.body.position.y += t
    b.body.position.x -= t
    b.body.position.y -= t
}
let time = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime

print(time)
```

---

### Results

Below are the benchmark times for each reference type. In each test, the `body` reference on the `Shape` class was changed. The code was built using release mode [-O] with Swift 5.1 targeting macOS 10.15.

`weak var body: Body!`: 0.1886 s

`var body: Body!`: 0.0167 s

`unowned body: Body!`: 0.0942 s

You can see using a strong reference in the computation above instead of a weak reference results in over 10x faster performance. Using `unowned` helps, but unfortunately it is still 5x slower. When running the code through the profiler, there appear to be additional runtime checks being performed resulting in much overhead.

**So the question is**, what are my options for having a simple back pointer to Body without incurring this ARC overhead. And furthermore why does this overhead seem so extreme? I suppose I could keep the strong reference cycle and break it manually. But I'm wondering if there is a better alternative?

**Update:**
Based on the answer, here is the result for
`unowned(unsafe) var body: Body!`: 0.0160 s

**Update2:**
As of Swift 5.2 (Xcode 11.4), I have noticed that unowned(unsafe) has much more overhead. Here is the result now for
`unowned(unsafe) var body: Body!`: 0.0804 s

Note: This is still true as of Xcode 12/Swift 5.3

Comment: Not sure if it's applicable in your case, but have you considered not using a class in favour of a `Struct` ideally with a custom made copy-on-write?

Comment: @Kamil.S Yes I have and it is faster (though not by much), but having a shared state was more convenient. I might return to this idea though.

Comment: @EpicByte that is some excellent research you did there! Great material for a short blog post :) thank you for this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I was writing up/investigating this issue, I eventually found a solution. To have a simple back pointer without the overhead checks of `weak` or `unowned` you can declare body as:

```
unowned(unsafe) var body: Body!
```

According to the Swift documentation:

> Swift also provides unsafe unowned references for cases where you need
> to disable runtime safety checks—for example, for performance reasons.
> As with all unsafe operations, you take on the responsibility for
> checking that code for safety.
>
> You indicate an unsafe unowned reference by writing unowned(unsafe).
> If you try to access an unsafe unowned reference after the instance
> that it refers to is deallocated, your program will try to access the
> memory location where the instance used to be, which is an unsafe
> operation

So it is clear these runtime checks can produce serious overhead in performance-critical code.

**Update**:
As of Swift 5.2 (Xcode 11.4), I have noticed that `unowned(unsafe)` has much more overhead. I now simply use strong references and break retain cycles manually, or try to avoid them entirely in performance-critical code.

Note: This is still true as of Xcode 12/Swift 5.3